# How can I generate a custom response example value in NSwag (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to generate a custom response example value using NSwag. When using Swashbuckle there are [attributes](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples) for it, but I'm not sure how to do it in NSwag.

I found this [thread](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/316), but I'm not familiar enough with Swagger to translate the code.

Does anyone have any complete examples of how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the expected JSON field and structure of the sample, you can implement this yourself by modifying the code in this blog: https://blog.rsuter.com/nswag-tutorial-implement-a-custom-operation-processor-to-define-redoc-code-samples/

Comment: If you’d like to contribute your implementations, please create a PR in NSwag.SwaggerGeneration.Processors, thx :-)